# Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with keyword arguments '{'uidb64': '', 'token': ''}' not found

Tags: python, django

urls.py

```
app_name='user'
urlpatterns = [ 
    re_path(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='user/password_reset_confirm.html'), name='password_reset_confirm'),
]
```

template

```
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'user:password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

shows the following error:

```
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with keyword arguments '{'uidb64': '', 'token': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$']
```

with values

```
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'user:password_reset_confirm' uidb64='hello' token='howareyou' %}


Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with keyword arguments '{'uidb64': 'hello', 'token': 'howareyou'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$']
```

Comment: `uid` and `token` are empty in your template, but the URL rule requires them to have at least one character.

Comment: @Klaus D I tried giving some values to those parameters but still the same error I have updated my question

Comment: `howareyou` does not match your token regex.

Comment: @Klaus D.  I am using a default auth view, so taken and uid should be generated by the view right?  path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='user/password_reset_email.html'),name='password_reset'),

Answer (score 1):

`token=howareyou` will not match the regex pattern for `token`.

The expected token should have a hyphen in the middle, e.g.: `howare-you`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', #rest of it),
]
```